# sumproduct of numbers corresponding to criteria that are part of a list

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif, sumproduct

I have an array of numbers, each number having a tag associated to it in a different column.
I need to sum up the numbers in the array for which the tag is included in a different array that lists the tags which are allowed to be summed up.

=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B7, COUNTIF(A1:A7,A10:A12))

Here a simplified example:

[image: example]

The output should be 400 (since only Prod A and Prod B are the list a10:a12)

Any hint? Is in Google Sheet. Have tried to combine sumproduct and countif but problem with non matching array sizes. And am not a wiz... Thank you much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter function to first filter the values from 1st array based on 2nd array. Then simply use SUM to sum it up

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B7,COUNTIF(E1:E2,A1:A7)))
```

This works in Google Sheet by default, and in Excel for O365 users

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: even simpler. I was stuck on sumproduct. Thank you @gangula

Answer (score 2):

Combine SUMPRODUCT with SUMIFS:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($B$1:$B$7;$A$1:$A$7;$A$13:$A$15))
```

Notice the change if we replace `C` with `Other`:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Looks like this works just in Excel but not Google Sheets. For Google Sheets you need a different formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$7;$A$13:$A$15;0)>0;0));$B$1:$B$7)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! Much appreciated particularly for taking the time to finding a Google Sheet specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sumproduct function.

```
=sumproduct(($B$1:$B$7)*($A$1:$A$7=A10))
```

Drag this down to get desired answers.